# Magento2 Get order item from collection in date range

Tags: magento2

i want to get order item from order collection on weekly basis and i wrote blow code . i just want to confirm that its right way or we can do better than this way please advice

```
public function execute()
    {

        $filepath = 'export/customerlist.csv';
        $this->directory->create('export');

       

        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
        $header = ['Sku', 'Name', 'Price','Qty','Date'];
        $stream->writeCsv($header);



        $orders = $this->getOrderCollectionByDateRange();
            if($orders->getTotalCount() > 0) { 
                foreach($orders as $_order) {
                    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($_order->getEntityId());
                    foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
                        $data = [];
                        $data[] = $_item->getSku();
                        $data[] = $_item->getName();
                        $data[] = $_item->getPrice();
                        $data[] = $_item->getQtyOrdered();
                        $data[] = $order->getCreatedAt();
                        $stream->writeCsv($data);
                       
                    }
                   
                }
            }
    }


    public function getOrderCollectionByDateRange(){

        $currentDate = $this->date->date('Y-m-d');
        $previousDate = $this->date->date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate."-2 days"));
        $startDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($previousDate)); // start date
        $endDate = date("Y-m-d ", strtotime($currentDate)); // end date
        $orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$startDate, 'to'=>$endDate));
        echo $orders->getSelect();

        return $orders;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm your way is the right way to filter Order collection by date range.

Your code could be optimized by removing redundant code:

- check Order Total count because if there are no orders, the code inside `foreach` won't reach.
- reload order by orderRepository because order items is instance of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` and it support call `getAllVisibleItems` method as you need.

So, replace your code:

```
$orders = $this->getOrderCollectionByDateRange();
            if($orders->getTotalCount() > 0) { 
                foreach($orders as $_order) {
                    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($_order->getEntityId());
                    foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
                        $data = [];
                        $data[] = $_item->getSku();
                        $data[] = $_item->getName();
                        $data[] = $_item->getPrice();
                        $data[] = $_item->getQtyOrdered();
                        $data[] = $order->getCreatedAt();
                        $stream->writeCsv($data);
                       
                    }
                   
                }
            }
```

To

```
$orders = $this->getOrderCollectionByDateRange();
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $data = [];
        $data[] = $item->getSku();
        $data[] = $item->getName();
        $data[] = $item->getPrice();
        $data[] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        $data[] = $order->getCreatedAt();
        $stream->writeCsv($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: if($orders->getTotalCount() > 0)  why i remove this?

Comment: ok understand great help thanks

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: i need some more modification in this if same product order by 2 customers then its show in single row i mean qty and price multiply.